# Strange behavior for update an entry in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, lodash

I like to update an entry in mongodb. But lodash only update one value in the array. I send this object to my node.js server:

```
{ _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda3,
  name: 'blueberry',
  uuid: 'b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d',
  major: '12345',
  minor: '12345',
  position: 'Kantine',
  __v: 18,
  messages:
   [ { _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda4,
       timeRange: [Object],
       url: '',
       message: 'j',
       title: 'jv',
       messageType: 'text' },
     { _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda4,
       timeRange: [Object],
       url: '',
       message: 'j',
       title: 'jv',
       messageType: 'text' } ] }
```

Here is the code for the update of the mongodb-entry:

```
// Updates an existing ibeacons in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  Ibeacons.findById(req.params.id, function (err, ibeacons) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!ibeacons) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(ibeacons, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, ibeacons);
    });
  });
};
```

But I get this as result:

```
{ _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda3,
  name: 'blueberry',
  uuid: 'b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d',
  major: '12345',
  minor: '12345',
  position: 'Kantine',
  __v: 18,
  messages:
   [ { _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda4,
       timeRange: [Object],
       url: '',
       message: 'j',
       title: 'jv',
       messageType: 'text' },
     { _id: 5593df7c087e59a00c04cda4,
       timeRange: [Object],
       url: '',
       message: 'j',
       title: 'jv',
       messageType: 'text' } ] }
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: And what result would you expect instead? And what is the content of `req.body` in the code snippet you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get it. the version of lodash was on 2.4.1 now I updated it to 3.1.0 and it works. :D